# Flatten numpy array with list comprehension, alternative solutions

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array a with a.shape = (14, 3200, 2500)

I'm trying to extract non nan values from it to a (-1, 14) array.

This is my current code

```
nans = ~(np.isnan(a)).any(axis=0)
indices = np.where(nans)
vals = np.asarray([a[:, i, j] for i, j in zip(indices[0], indices[1])])
```

But I think I should be changing the list comprehension for a numpy built-in function but cant find a function that does this as this doesn't seem to be that fast. Anyone has a good suggestions?

Edit:
I'm also trying to get the indices where these values are so my outputs should be arrays with shapes (-1, 14), (-1, 2).
The second array is made with

```
np.stack((indices[0],indices[1])).transpose()
```

So the list comprehension should preserve the order

Comment: Why dont you flatten and then extract the non nan values?

Comment: Does flattening preserve the order? I'm also trying to get coordinates where these values area in the array. I'll add an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) followed by a [`.T`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) (transpose) solves the problem:

```
vals = a[:, indices[0], indices[1]].T
```

It can be checked that it returns the same array as your current approach:

```
nans = ~(np.isnan(a)).any(axis=0)
indices = np.where(nans)
vals = np.asarray([a[:, i, j] for i, j in zip(indices[0], indices[1])])

# changed the name for comparison purposes
vals2 = a[:, indices[0], indices[1]].T
print(np.isclose(vals, vals2).all())
```

**Output**

```
True
```

**Note**

The array `a`, (used for testing), was generated by:

```
a = np.random.random((14, 3200, 2500))
a[a < 0.3] = np.nan
```

Comment: Works like a charm for numpy array. Anyone stumbling over this solution take a note that this does not work for xarray.DataArray and you have to convert to numpy first